# How to determine version of FLASH with InstallShield 2009

Tags: installshield-2009

I am currently using InstallShield 2009 and one of the required components that needs to be installed in Adobe Flash Player. However, we only want to install it IF it is below a certain version.

For example, if we deploy our InstallShield setup.exe on a system where Flash is not installed we should install version 10.0.32.18 (which is included in the package), however if the system has a version of Flash installed that is newer then 10.0.32.18 we should not attempt to install it.

In the past when I was using Flash9 I would simply check System32\Macromed\Flash\flash9d.ocx version and if it was below 9.0.47.0 then install it - but now with Flash10 things get a little complicated - as I don't know what file to check.

Is there a general way (for all versions) that I can check what Flash is installed, or is there a specific way I can check what version of Flash 10 is installed and if it isn't then just check 9 as I did before?

Any help/advice would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In our installers, we check the value of the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Macromedia\Flash Player\CurrentVersion key in the registry.

It is a comma separated string (10,0,32,18), so the parsing is a bit different. But the format has be consistent for all the versions of flash that we care about.